# How to get "Publish Date" dynamic value from page using HtmlUnit in Java?

Tags: javascript, java, html

As a simple coding exercise, I am working on a small project that is comparing current system date to the dates present in few web-pages (to see if there is a new update). For most of them, everything works just fine, but there is one that is causing me some problems.

Page: https://access.redhat.com/security/security-updates/#/security-advisories

Value I am trying to get: Publish Date

Question: How can I do it in Java?

Tried using simple BufferedReader, tried saving whole page to a file - to no avail. I did some research and it seems like I need to use HtmlUnit, but I feel like I need advice to understand how does it work.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Logger.getLogger("com.gargoylesoftware").setLevel(Level.OFF);
    System.setProperty("org.apache.commons.logging.Log", "org.apache.commons.logging.impl.NoOpLog");

    String START_URL ="https://access.redhat.com/security/security-updates/#/security-advisories";

    try{

        WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.CHROME);

        webClient.getOptions().setCssEnabled(true);
        webClient.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(5000);

        HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage(START_URL);
        String pageContent = page.asText(); //this will NOT include dates
        System.out.println(pageContent);


    } catch (IOException ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

I would like to get the content of the first "Publish Date" box from a https://access.redhat.com/security/security-updates/#/security-advisories page, however no matter what approach I try, the dynamic value is never visible and cannot be stored/checked.

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {

        WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.CHROME);
        webClient.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage("https://access.redhat.com/security/security-updates/#/security-advisories");
        webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(15000);
        HtmlTable table = (HtmlTable) page.getElementById("DataTables_Table_0");
        for (HtmlTableRow row : table.getRows()) {
            List<HtmlElement> timeElements = row.getElementsByTagName("time");
            if (timeElements.size() > 0) {
                HtmlElement timeElement = timeElements.get(0);

                // GET THE TIME FROM THE CELL
                String time = timeElement.getAttribute("datetime"); // time in format "2019-05-08T17:34:20Z"
                System.out.println("TIME: " + time);
            } else {
                // This row does not contain a element with time tag
            }
        }

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

This is untested, maybe there is something to change in the path to the correct nodes, but this should give you a start :)

UPDATE:
I now tested it and it is printing the desired time to the console.
This ONE way of doing it. There are many other ways in HTMLUnit to get the Elements of the DOM you need. 
I suggest to read the [getting started document](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/gettingStarted.html) -> "Finding a specific Element".

Comment: Thank you for taking your time to reply, @Sunchezz. Ah, so this is the syntax - interesting, I should dig more into HtmlUnit documentation.

As for code you have provided, unfortunately it returns an Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException at HTMLtest.Main.main(Main.java:33). I will try to work on it tomorrow, thanks.

Comment: As stated several times here: waitForBackgroundJavaScript is NOT an option. You have to call it AFTER every request (in your case after getPage).

Comment: And please do not disable logging if you are hunting for problems. Maybe the log includes useful hints.

Comment: @TheC. You also can retrieve the "next" button and simulate a click on it, wait for the next page and retrieve the next dates, all in a loop, if you need all dates ;)